# Can't set variable as html element attribute

Tags: angular

I found a problem that I do not know how to solve.

If you use this template, so there is no problem:

```
<li *ngFor="#supplier of supplierList | async">
    <a (click)="changeSupplier($event)">
        <span>{{supplier.id}}: {{supplier.name}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Output is e.g.:

```
<li>
    <a>
        <span>1: Sony</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a>
        <span>2: Samsung</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

If I edit a template and try to set the "supplier.id" into html attribute "data-supplierid":

```
<li *ngFor="#supplier of supplierList | async">
    <a (click)="changeSupplier($event)" data-supplierid="{{supplier.id}}">
        <span>{{supplier.name}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

An error appears:

```
Can't bind to 'supplierid' since it isn't a known native property ("i>
                    <li *ngFor="#supplier of supplierList | async">
                        <a (click)="changeSupplier($event)" [ERROR ->]data-supplierid="{{supplier.id}}">
                            <span>{{supplier.name}}</span>
                        </a>
```

Comment: `attr.data-supplierid`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Default is property binding. For attribute binding use either

```
attr.data-supplierid="{{supplier.id}}"
```

or

```
[attr.data-supplierid]="supplier.id"
```

Comment: and what if I want to add a string in that attribute plus that variable? EX:
attr.data-supplierid="accordion + {{supplier.id}}" in order to get
attr.data-supplierid="accordion1" 
attr.data-supplierid="accordion2"

Comment: Just omit `{{}}` and be good. `[]` and `{{}}` are **never** used together on the same attribute.

Comment: can I use like this? attr.data-supplierid="accordion{{supplier.id}}"

Comment: Yes, this will work as well